# C#: Converting binary to axb matrix

Tags: c#, matlab, matrix, binaryfiles

I am trying to read a binary file (.bin) and convert the resources of the file into a matrix. The code I use to get the file is here.

```
using (BinaryReader Reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(string.Format("{0}{1}.bin", DefaultFilePath, "MyBinaryFile"), FileMode.Open)))
{
    //the code to convert binary to AxB matrix here.
    byteArray = Reader.ReadBytes(100000);
    float myFloat = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(byteArray, 0);
}
```

I need to write a piece of code which can convert the resources of a binary file into a AxB matrix. From the code above, you can see that I convert binary file into Byte[], then to float, but I am stuck in here.

In Matlab, you can read .bin file easily and get the AxB array such as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600355/read-binary-matrix-from-a-file-in-matlab).

How can I proceed?

Comment: `.bin` is not a defined file format - what format is this file in?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen it is a binary file [link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/binaryfiles/info)

Comment: If you read the link you just posted you would know that knowing just that "it is a binary file" does not give you any information about what it contains and in what kind of format. It's usually also much harder to guess the format of a binary file than text-based files.

Comment: Oh sorry. I am kind of new with coding, sorry for my rawness. The file should contain 32x500 float values for a second. For example, If this file is generated from a 5 second recording, it should contain 32x2500 float values.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is just a long list of 32-bit floats, you already got the first value converter correctly. Now you just need to do the rest by adding a loop and incrementing the second argument for `ToSingle` by 4 each time.

Or, since you're already using a `BinaryReader` you could just use its `ReadSingle` method in a loop. If you want a two-dimensional matrix, using a multidimensional array might be a good idea.

```
// In reality you might want to figure out the array size based on the file size
float[,] floatArray = new float[5000, 32];

using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(string.Format("{0}{1}.bin", DefaultFilePath, "MyBinaryFile"), FileMode.Open)))
{
    for (x = 0; x < floatArray.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < floatArray.GetLength(1); y++)
            floatArray[x, y] = reader.ReadSingle();
    }
}
```

Note: you might need to flip things around depending on whether your data file and desired memory representation is row-major or column-major.

Also remember that multidimensional arrays are contiguous in memory, so if your file is huge, you might run into problems processing it.